# How to return the Original sentence instead of lower case sentence

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I have a short code as that I would like to print out the original sentence extracted instead of the one in lower case.The code is as follows

```
import re
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
def foo():
    txt = "Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized. Breast cancer is 100 times more frequent in women than in men.\
    Factors associated with an increased exposure to estrogen have also been elucidated including early menarche, late menopause, later age\
    at first pregnancy, or nulliparity. The use of hormone replacement therapy has been confirmed as a risk factor, although mostly limited to \
    the combined use of estrogen and progesterone, as demonstrated in the WHI (2). Analysis showed that the risk of breast cancer among women using \
    estrogen and progesterone was increased by 24% compared to placebo. A separate arm of the WHI randomized women with a prior hysterectomy to \
    conjugated equine estrogen (CEE) versus placebo, and in that study, the use of CEE was not associated with an increased risk of breast cancer (3).\
    Unlike hormone replacement therapy, there is no evidence that oral contraceptive (OCP) use increases risk. A large population-based case-control study \
    examining the risk of breast cancer among women who previously used or were currently using OCPs included over 9,000 women aged 35 to 64 \
    (half of whom had breast cancer) (4). The reported relative risk was 1.0 (95% CI, 0.8 to 1.3) among women currently using OCPs and 0.9 \
    (95% CI, 0.8 to 1.0) among prior users. In addition, neither race nor family history was associated with a greater risk of breast cancer among OCP users."
    words = txt
    corpus = " ".join(words).lower()
    sentences1 = sent_tokenize(corpus)
    a = [" ".join([sentences1[i-1],j]) for i,j in enumerate(sentences1) if 'risk' in word_tokenize(j)]   


    for i in a:
        print i,'\n','\n'

foo()
```

what i keep getting is this(for example)

```
>>risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized
```

instead of this:

```
>>Risk factors for breast cancer have been well characterized.
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns, this is part of a larger code that works with .lower() texts, thats why I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
corpus = " ".join(words).lower()
```

It looks like you are using `.lower()` on the string so you can compare it to `risk` later easily. As you have noticed this lowers the entire string and there is no easy way to reverse that operation.

To circumvent this, you can instead compare `risk` to `word_tokenize(j).lower()` instead. Change these lines

```
corpus = " ".join(words).lower()
a = [" ".join([sentences1[i-1],j]) for i,j in enumerate(sentences1) if 'risk' in word_tokenize(j)]
```

to

```
corpus = " ".join(words)
a = [" ".join([sentences1[i-1],j]) for i,j in enumerate(sentences1) if 'risk' in word_tokenize(j).lower()]
```

This will preserve the string in its original state, while still being able to compare to `risk` easily.

Comment: Thanks, My biggest issue that I have a user input( e.g of string 'risk', which is automatically converted to .lower(), that's why I use corpus in lower case. So if I have capitalized words in corpus, its harder. I guess I will have to figure out how to extract.